# Ocelot Swagger MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot showing "No operations defined in spec!"

Tags: .net-core, swagger, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using Ocelot gateway and for swagger document using "**MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot**" library.
For some swagger Key, swagger UI is showing "No operations defined in spec!" and swagger JSON is coming without paths like

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Admin API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {},
  "components": {
    "schemas": {}
  }
}
```

Ocelot Configuration Route is

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/admin/v{version}/{everything} ",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/admin/v{version}/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [],
      "QoSOptions": {
        "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 3,
        "DurationOfBreak": 1000,
        "TimeoutValue": 900000
      },
      "SwaggerKey": "AdminAPI"
    }
```

and Swagger Configuration is

```
 "SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "AdminAPI",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "Admin API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
    
  ]
```

after reviewing the **MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot** source code, it looks like something to do with the  version in the downstream path, any clue on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that **MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot** is not considering {version} while doing Ocelot transformation.

**RouteOptions** has a property **TransformByOcelotConfig** which is set to true by default, so once swagger JSON is obtained from downstream, the transformation will be done.
here, it will try to find the route from the route configuration like below and if not found it will delete the route from swagger JSON

```
private static RouteOptions FindRoute(IEnumerable<RouteOptions> routes, string downstreamPath, string basePath)
        {
            string downstreamPathWithBasePath = PathHelper.BuildPath(basePath, downstreamPath);
            return routes.FirstOrDefault(p
                => p.CanCatchAll
                    ? downstreamPathWithBasePath.StartsWith(p.DownstreamPathWithSlash, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    : p.DownstreamPathWithSlash.Equals(downstreamPathWithBasePath, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

The problem is **StartsWith** will return false since swagger JSON path will be like

```
/api/admin/v{version}/Connections
```

and route config is like

```
/api/admin/v{version}/{everything}
```

and version will replace with the version given in swagger options so that it will become

```
/api/admin/v1/{everything}
```

Fix to this problem will be

1. Either set "TransformByOcelotConfig":false in swagger option

```
"SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "AdminAPI",
      "TransformByOcelotConfig":false,
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "Admin API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
    
  ]
```

2. Or Change the route, just to have {everything} keyword

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/admin/{everything} ",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/admin/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [],
      "QoSOptions": {
        "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 3,
        "DurationOfBreak": 1000,
        "TimeoutValue": 900000
      },
      "SwaggerKey": "AdminAPI"
    }
```